# How to append new image items with Masonry and AJAX without overlapping on window scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax, append, jquery-masonry

I am trying to use Masonry to append new elements on my container on page scroll. I am trying to use AJAX for it and here is my UPDATED code:

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                var container = document.querySelector('#entries-content-ul');
                imagesLoaded( container, function() {
                    new Masonry( container, {
                        itemSelector: '.box',
                        isAnimated:true,
                        animationOptions: {
                        duration: 700,
                        easing:'linear',
                        queue :false
                        }
                        });
                    });
                var ajaxstart=1;
                var tpage = 2;
                function lastAddedLiveFunc()
                {
                    $('div#lastPostsLoader').html('');
                    $.get("{/literal}{$baseurl}{literal}/votejson.php?page="+tpage, function(data){
                        if (data != "") {
                            $data = $( data );                      
                            $('#load_image').css('display','none');
                            var container = document.querySelector('#entries-content-ul'); 
                            var msnry;
                            // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
                            $("#entries-content-ul").append(data).imagesLoaded( data, function() {
                            ajaxstart=1;
                            msnry = new Masonry( container );
                            });


                        }else{
                        ajaxstart=2;
                        }
                        $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
                    });
                };
});
```

New items are being added to the page on document scroll. I am unable though to append these new items to the current masonry layout. This is why I am creating a second masonry container. On the first new set ot items, they are being generated on the top of the page and then, they move down to the bottom in a quite ugly way. After that all new Items are being added correctly, sometimes they overlap each other, sometimes not, I guess non cached images overlap. What I want to achieve is to be able to find the ".box" html item from `data` and then append it to the existing masonry container. I have been struggling to do this for some time now after reading all related questions here, but still no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I decided to try using Isotope instead and everything is working just perfect!

```
var $container = $('#entries-content-ul');

                    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
                        $container.isotope({
                            itemSelector : '.box'
                            });
                            });
                var tpage = 2;
                function lastAddedLiveFunc()
                {
                    $('div#lastPostsLoader').html('');
                    $.get("{/literal}{$baseurl}{literal}/votejson.php?page="+tpage, function(data){
                        if (data != "") {
                            var el = $(data);
                            el.imagesLoaded(function() {
                                $container.append(el).isotope('appended', el, true);
                                });
                        ajaxstart=1;                    
                        }else{
                        ajaxstart=2;
                        }
                        $('div#lastPostsLoader').empty();
                    });
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue recently while using `imagesloaded` with `Isotope` (a plugin on top of masonry.js), but this was restricted to Firefox.

After some debugging, I found out that the problem was due to the `load` event on images not firing correctly (guessing on images loaded from cache). Thus the masonry script is executed without images completely loading up, and giving an incorrect height value to `masonry` and hence, the overlapping when images fully load up.

When you scroll down, you may be invoking the `masonry` script again, but this time with images fully loaded and hence, the proper arrangement.

To get around this, I totally removed the `imagesloaded` check and had to explicitly set the height/width parameter of the images in its container. This way, even if images are loading, you can trigger the masonry script which now gets the correct height/width and thus, no overlapping.

To illustrate:

```
Previous HTML:

<div class="image-container">
    <img src="some-random-goat-image.jpg" alt="Crazy goat" />
</div>

New HTML:
<div class="image-container" style="height: 400px; width: 200px">
    <img src="some-random-goat-image.jpg" alt="Crazy goat again" />
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If you have dynamic height images, you could manually trigger the load event for the images when they finish loading up and fire the `masonry` script after the last image finishes loading:

Assuming `data` is the result HTML returned:

```
$(hiddendiv).html(data);

var 
$data = $(hiddendiv).html(),
images = $data.find('img'),
loadcount = 0;

images.one('load', function(){
        var 
        imgheight = $(this).height,
        containerid = $(this).data('cid');
        $data.find('div[data-cid="' + containerid + '"]').css('height', imgheight);
        loadcount++;

    if(loadedcount === images.length ) {
        //Append $data to page and initialize masonry after last image loads up
    }
})
.each(function(){
   if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been thinking that something like that may be the problem. However the images that are being loaded on my site are not with the same height. Maybe I should find a method of calculating each image's height(width is the same) before appending them to the container. Any advise on that?

Comment: @G.Vasilev I've updated my answer. Try using the code above and let me know if it works! Cheers!

Comment: I am unable to successfully integrate your code with mine. Maybe I'm doing it wrong. `Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'find' `